# No database selected error in CodeIgniter running on MAMP stack

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, mamp

I have ci installed on a regular MAMP stack, and I’m working on [this tutorial](http://fwebde.com/php/simple-crud-with-codeigniter/).  However, I have only gone through the Created section, and currently I am getting a No database selected error.

Model:

```
<?php 
class submit_model extends Model {

    function submitForm($school, $district) {
        $data = array(
            'school' => $school,
            'district' => $district
        );

        $this->db->insert('your_stats', $data);
    }

}
```

View:

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>

<?php echo form_open('main'); ?>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_input('school'); ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_input('district'); ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
    </p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class Main extends controller {

    function index() {

        // Check if form is submitted
        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
            $school = $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('school'));
            $district = $this->input->xss_clean($this->input->post('district'));

            $this->load->model('submit_model');
            // Add the post
            $this->submit_model->submitForm($school, $district);
        }
        $this->load->view('main_view');
    }
}
```

database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost:8889";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "root";
$db['default']['database'] = "stats_test";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = "http://localhost:8888/ci/";
...
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
...
$config['uri_protocol']    = "AUTO";
```

So, how come it’s giving me this error message?

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1046

No database selected

INSERT INTO `your_stats` (`school`, `district`) VALUES ('TJHSST', 'FairFax')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving your password blank.

I think that's the default for WAMP and XAMPP. It could be for MAMP as well.

Comment: No, unfortunately in the startup screen MAMP explicitly sets both username and password to root.

Comment: You probably need to check your database name.

Comment: The db name matches the one I listed above, in database.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are (auto)loading the database class?

double check this, and also check the database name is correct.

Comment: Yes, I have $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

The database name (stats_test) matches the one I created in phpMyAdmin through MAMP.  your_stats should be the table within that db.  Am I supposed to do something special with phpMyAdmin in MAMP?